# magento 2 admin 503 error when try to edit grouped product

Tags: magento, magento2

I'm getting 503 error when try to edit grouped products. Based on my investigation if my grouped product has more than 130 simple products assigned then im not able to open grouped product. Im having more than 200 grouped products which are assigned to 200+ simple products. and not able to edit these grouped products.

**Error message:**

503 backend fetch failed

**Nginx access log:**

[26/Jan/2018:16:25:16 +0800] "GET /backoffice/catalog/product/edit/id/61892/key/c6bd39586866566bd784f5dd59744c7f9a909c02ff54e32f9fc7643b6f815e4f/ HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36" "60.001" "-"

System configuration: Magento 2.1.7, php-fpm, nginx varnish & redis

Have tried below suggestions:

1. Setting http_resp_hdr_len in varnish
   http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/varnish/tshoot-varnish-503.html
2. Increased max_execution_time to 3600 seconds and post_max_size to 512MB in php.ini file
3. disabled php-fpm request_terminate_timeout

But still no luck. Can anyone please advice on this.

**Edit 1:**

I have enabled profiler and traced one of the grouped product by editing from backoffice

**Steps:**
1. Enable profiler
2. Login to backoffice
3. Edit grouped product (id: xxx)

This product # xxx is a grouped product and 271 simple products are assigned to this grouped products.

**Result:**
There are 271 queries generated like below query and each query returning 73441 rows. 73441 rows are having same result.

```
SELECT `main`.`value_id`, `main`.`value` AS `file`, `main`.`media_type`, `entity`.`row_id`, `value`.`label`, `value`.`position`, `value`.`disabled`, `default_value`.`label` AS `label_default`, `default_value`.`position` AS `position_default`, `default_value`.`disabled` AS `disabled_default`, `value_video`.`provider` AS `video_provider`, `value_video`.`url` AS `video_url`, `value_video`.`title` AS `video_title`, `value_video`.`description` AS `video_description`, `value_video`.`metadata` AS `video_metadata`, `default_value_video`.`provider` AS `video_provider_default`, `default_value_video`.`url` AS `video_url_default`, `default_value_video`.`title` AS `video_title_default`, `default_value_video`.`description` AS `video_description_default`, `default_value_video`.`metadata` AS `video_metadata_default` FROM `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` AS `main` INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity` AS `entity` ON main.value_id = entity.value_id LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` AS `value` ON main.value_id = value.value_id AND value.store_id = 0 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` AS `default_value` ON main.value_id = default_value.value_id AND default_value.store_id = 0 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_video` AS `value_video` ON value.value_id = value_video.value_id AND value.store_id = value_video.store_id LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_video` AS `default_value_video` ON default_value.value_id = default_value_video.value_id AND default_value.store_id = default_value_video.store_id WHERE (main.attribute_id = '90') AND (main.disabled = 0) AND (entity.row_id = '61939') ORDER BY IF(value.position IS NULL, default_value.position, value.position) ASC
```

I hope this query is causing Backend fetch failed error and product page is not able to editable.

Comment: can you provide more logs (nginx error log / php-fpm logs, magento log..) ?

Comment: I have enabled profiler and traced one of the grouped product. Please refer the ticket. I have not received any nginx/php-fpm/magento errors. The edit page was loading for more that 60 seconds and it was throwing "Backend fetch failed error". In access nginx log alone I received 499 error code.